# Javascript Image path issue with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am setting up a webpack config as a starting point for my future projects and I need some help.

Before explaining my problem, I have prepared a git repo.

```
git clone https://github.com/e3i6/webpackBasic.git
npm install
```

Then just with **npm start** and **npm run build**, you’ll see what I see: all the config files are there.

Currently, my issue with image path has two consequences:

1. From **./src/index.js**: to link "test.png" I need to write   **img.src =
   "./src/assets/test.png" (line 9)**   instead of   **img.src = "./assets/test.png"**  (which is the relative path).
2. When building the app (npm run build), the javascript does not change the path and the
   name which is an error: my webpack config renames each files to
   avoid a caching problem. In fact, the mentioned URL remains
   unchanged and even the path is wrong.

In the git repo, you can easily see my config. I thought it was the best way to understand the problem and help me fix this.

Thank you for any help you can give me!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem about webpack’s image paths.

The problem was that webpack could not resolve this:

```
cubeMat.diffuseTexture = new Texture("./assets/background.png", scene);
```

Apparently, with webpack you have to import images before using them otherwise it will not compile correctly.

```
import img2 from “./assets/background.png”;

…

cubeMat.diffuseTexture = new Texture(img2, scene);
```

I’m a newbie with webpack so it was not obvious to me.

Have a nice day!